# Calculating hypotenuse for length of ray

Tags: xna, .net-4.5

I'm certain this is simple for someone, but I'm not too great with trigonometry.

As title says, I'm trying to calculate the hypotenuse of a triangle given a float of distance between the camera and a model's boundingbox, and the direction the ray is traveling.

Image for better explanation:

[image]

Comment: is `possibly irrellevent value` known?  If it is just use the Pythagorean Theorem.

Comment: if not you can use Angle-Side-Angle to find the area of a triangle.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math and not directly related to coding.

Comment: It appears that all you know is "Hit". But to determine the distance between "start Pos" and "End Pos" you also need to know either: "angle" or "Possibly Irellevent Value" or "End Pos". without that, the hyp can't be determined. But it is rare in 2d game programming that you would not know at least one of the others.

Comment: First off, sorry about not being more clear of it's relevance to coding. Secondly, how could an ASA function be written in c#?
Also, this is a 3D game with a ray in a 2D plane. Angle could be potentially found as the direction of Ray is known

Answer (score 0):

Treat "Start Pos" as 0, 0.
Then the tip of your ray is at (Rx, Ry).
This forms a similar triangle to the big one (see the picture below).

So you know that the ratio between the height/width of the smaller triangle is the same as the height/width of the larger triangle.  So this is true:
Dy / Dx = Ry / Rx

Since you know Dx, Ry and Rx, you can solve for Dy:

**Dy = Dx * Ry / Rx**

Now you can find the length you need with:

**L = sqrt(Dx^2 + Dy^2)**

[image]

Comment: The problem with this is that I can't find Rx. I do have Dx, and can get the **direction** of L, but don't know the scaling of Dx to find Rx such that it is still proportional to Ry and Dy.

Comment: What do you mean by you "can get the direction of L" then? Is this an angle from the camera? You said it was a ray.  A ray is a direction, it has an X and Y value.  Help me understand what you're starting with and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Let's say my camera is at (0, 0) like you have there. I am casting a ray forward with a perpetually infinite length. Somewhere in that direction, lower or higher, is a 3D bounding box. I need to find the length between where the ray starts (the camera's position) and where the ray would vertically (or horizontally) meet the first point of the bounding box. I have the length from the camera to the bounding box point, but that length is different than from the ray to the bounding box due to diagonals.